# How can I calculate evolutionary timescales of low mass stars?

Tags: astrophysics, astronomy, stars

How can I calculate how long a star of a given mass will spend on an evolutionary branch before evolving off it?

I'm thinking about the evolution of low mass stars from the subgiant branch to the red giant branch and beyond. I know of timescales such as dynamic and nuclear etc, and I want to learn how I can calculate how long a star of a given mass will spend on a branch before evolving off it.

I've tried using the nuclear timescale equation, but this relies on having Hydrogen in the core, and evolved stars may not have any H in the core.

I've seen on the internet I'm aiming for a value between 1000 and 1 billion years, but don't know how to work this out.

Thanks for your help.

I also posted here: https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/51105/how-can-i-calculate-evolutionary-timescales-of-low-mass-stars?noredirect=1#

Comment: Might be a better fit for [astronomy.se]

Comment: I didn't know there was a Stack Overflow for Astronomy. Thanks